# How to pass the tokens to strstr () for searching the similar strings?

Tags: strtok, strstr

I am trying to split the given string containing the spaces into multiple strings.
Then I am trying to pass these strings/tokenz to the strstr() for searching the similar strings from the given file. The output should show the matched strings in the output screen. I am able to split the string into multiple strings but I am facing problems in strstr(). It's not searching and providing me the matched words. Here is the code:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #define MAXCHAR 20000

    int main(){
    
        FILE *fp,*fp2; 
        char str[MAXCHAR]; 
        char str2[MAXCHAR]; 
        char str3; 
        char delim[] = " ";        
        fp = fopen("blacklist.txt", "r");           
        if (fp == NULL)
        {               
            printf("Cannot open %s\n", "blacklist.txt");
            return 1;
        }        
        fp2 = fopen("email.txt", "r");    
        if (fp2 == NULL) 
        {
            printf("Cannot open %s\n", "email.txt"); 
            return 1;
        }
        while (fgets(str2, MAXCHAR, fp2) != NULL){
            char *ptr = strtok(str2, delim);
            while(ptr != NULL){
                printf("%s\n", ptr);
                ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
            }   
           while (fgets(str, MAXCHAR, fp) != NULL){                       
           rewind(fp2);                         
                while (ptr != NULL){                                
                char *p = strstr(str, ptr);            
                    if (p != NULL && (p == str || p[-1] == '.')) 
                    { 
                       int n = strcspn(str, "\n");   
                       int n2 = strcspn(ptr, "\n");  
                        printf("domain matched on %.*s for %.*s\n", n2, ptr, n, str);
                        break;
                    }
               }
            }
       }
           fclose(fp);    
           fclose(fp2);   
           return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop after the `rewind` is never entered, because you made sure that `ptr` is `null` (the only way to exit the loop containing `strtok` ).
You are splitting the string and printing them out, but the program has no access to the split strings.

I think it would be better to structure your program like this:

```
while strtok != null
  strcpy to an array and increment a counter for strings

while read a line
  for each member of the array
    strstr(line, string)
```